# ReactJS toggle burger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to code a toggle menu in ReactJS in a way that I can understand. I understand that my code is a newbie and I need some help to understand what I'm doing wrong here, I'm stuck in this for almost 12 hours.

With the function display(), I'm trying to add a new className to the nav so would be "topnav responsive" so in this way, I could activate the new style within the @media CSS to make a responsive menu.

```
function Menu() {
  const [showMenu, setMenu] = useState();

  function display() {
    const setMenu = () => {
      let toggle = document.querySelector(".topnav");
      if (toggle.className === "topnav") {
        toggle.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        toggle.className = "topnav";
      }
    };
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container container-nav">
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            display();
          }}
          className="logo"
        >
          <img src={logo} alt="" />
        </div>
        <nav className="topnav">
          <ul>
            <li className="icon">
              <img src={burgerMenu} alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

** CSS **

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: You told being stuck. But exactly is the problem?

Comment: My menu burger doesn't dropdown when I click.

I understand that I can toggle something in React like this:

```
const [showMenu, setMenu] = useState(false);

  let menu;
  
  if(showMenu){
      menu = <div>
          <h1>example</h1>
      </div>

...

return(
  <div>{menu}</div>
)
  }
 ```

But in the approach from the original post it's not working. I'm trying to transform this code with hooks.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you were trying to do something like this?

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function Menu() {
  const [showMenu, setMenu] = useState();

  function display() {
    setMenu(value=>!value)
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <div className='container container-nav'>
        <div
          onClick={display}
          className='logo'
        >
          <img src={logo} alt='' />
        </div>
        <nav className={`topnav${showMenu?' responsive':null}`}>
          <ul>
            <li className='icon'>
              <img src={burgerMenu} alt='' />
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=''>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=''>About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=''>Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=''>Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Rule of thumb is you should avoid the DOM API most of the time when using React. If you are doing something like `document.querySelector(x)`, you might actually be wanting to use a Ref (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

This time, however, a simple condition will suffice.

Comment: Thank you! Now the div moves but not exactly how I want. I will try to understand what you just explained and improve the code.

Comment: function display() {
    setMenu(value=>!value)
  }

Could you please explain better what this function is doing?
I think that receives a value and returns the opposite of it. If I pass true, would return false. 

But when the display() it's called, what happens with it?

Comment: What you need to change now is your css code.

Comment: As for the setMenu(value=>!value), the setter function returned from useEffect can receive a callback instead of a value. Such callback will receive the state's current value as its first argument.

Comment: Obrigado irmão!

I fixed the CSS yesterday and all worked just fine.